# Why is $location.path not working until I click on the screen

Tags: angularjs, amazon-cognito

I have the following code that aims to redirect to the './mainlandingpage' after a successful authentication.  Here is the code from the controller:

```
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            // pass token to use for getting credentials later
            sessionStorage.Token = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
            $scope.messageText = globalData.LoggingIn;
            $location.path('/mainlandingpage');
            console.log(' after location');

        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
```

The console from Firebug shows the following:

```
POST https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/200 OK 704ms 
POST https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/200 OK 401ms 
after location
```

So, I know that the code went through the $location.path line but my problem is nothing happens to the page until I click something on the page (doesn't need to be a button).  Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying `$location` path from outside Angular world(i.e. custom event authenticateUser's `onSuccess` event). That's why the changes aren't being reflecting in instantly in the URL.

Changing angular bindings from outside world doesn't update current changes directly on the page unless it runs through digest cycle. To make those changes happen, you have to call digest cycle manually to tell `Angular digest` system that some changes have been happened in application context. Since you have to  kick off digest cycle to make them in sync. For kick off digest cycle you could use `$timeout`(most preferred)/`$scope.$apply` function.

```
//inject `$timeout` in controller function
$timeout(function(){
   $location.path('/mainlandingpage'); 
})
```

Comment: @leoc Glad to know that, Thanks :)\

Answer (score 0):

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser('authenticationDetails', function( $location) {
$location.path('/mainlandingpage');
       //your code here.......
});
```

You need to declare the $location in function as shown above.try this

Comment: dependency can be injected on `controller` level function, what you have is incorrect..